# Facebook only wont load on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: internet, laptop, facebook

Facebook is the only page that wont load properly on my laptop. It just loads the basic text version . No matter what internet connection or browser I use the problem still exists. And even booting a different OS through a virtual box and I still have the same problem. Facebook is the only webpage that this happens on, everything else is perfect

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? That could be causing issues.

Comment: Nope just tried turning it off and still not working

Comment: Are you at work? A company filter could be blocking Facebook.

Comment: Nope, no matter what connection im one its still doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an actual answer, more a me too, but with enough detail that I thought it would not fit neatly into a comment.

Essentially I have the same issue. It's only with 1 machine on my network. Other machines on the same network, including the same version of Ubuntu (12.04) and the same browsers are OK.

- Facebook is the only site that seems to flat out out refuse to load
- I get a "No data received" from chrome, and "The connection to the
  server was reset while the page was loading." on Firefox
- DNS Servers are reported identically to other machines on the network
- There is no proxy or proxy settings in use
- The is nothing special in iptables
- There is nothing unusual in /etc/hosts
- A virtual machine hosted by this machine can access facebook.com just fine

I'm not even sure where to look at this point. Facebook really isn't that big a loss, on the rare occasions I need it I can do so elsewhere, but the nature of the problem is intriguing, and pointing out perhaps gaping flaws in my linux/networking knowledge.

Any idea on where/how to look would be appreciated.